# How to select element if another element is set to display: flex; with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a full screen, fixed pop-up that toggles between display: none; and display: flex;. I want to be able to select the body tag **when my pop-up is set to display: flex;** in order to disable scrolling behind the pop-up.

So something along the lines of "If popup = display: flex; then body = overflow: hidden;"

How can I do this with a little JS or Jquery? Or if there is a better method, I'm open to suggestions.

Here is the code I'm using to open the pop-up:

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        function toggle_visibility(id) {
            event.preventDefault();
           var e = document.getElementById(id);
           if(e.style.display == 'flex')
              e.style.display = 'none';
           else
              e.style.display = 'flex';
        }

    //-->
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('id-of-popup');">Clickable item to open the Popup</a>
```

Comment: I would suggest adding a class to the `body` when the popup is opened (in the JS that opens the popup) and use that instead of trying to trigger off of the state of some property of the popup.

Comment: @HereticMonkey How would I go about doing that with the code I'm using above?

Comment: Instead of affecting the element whose ID is captured by your function, use `.classList` to add/remove a class from the body. In your CSS you can then target the popup with `body.popup-active #popup` to change the display value.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen You'd have to toggle a class specific to the popup's ID in order for that to work. Basically, the trade off is having a `body.class-specific-to-popup-id #popup-id` for every popup, or just toggle a single class on both the popup and the body...

Comment: The ID is just to keep things close to what OP was doing, but ideally, a general `.popup` class would be better. And since it'd be daft to have more than one popup at a time, it should be a good and clean way to handle things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd change your code around to use classes. Add a style sheet with the following:

```css
.popup { display: none; }
.popup.show { display: flex; }
.popup-shown { overflow: hidden; }
```

Then alter your JavaScript to take advantage of those:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.classList.toggle('show');
    document.body.classList.toggle('popup-shown');
}
```

I'm assuming your popup gets the class "popup" here.

This takes advantage of the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) interface, which is available on modern browsers, which notably does not include Internet Explorer. There is [a polyfill on MDN's page for the interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Polyfill) for browsers that don't support it natively.

Answer (score 0):

So first, you will need to get the pop-up element with querySelecor. Let's say the pop-up has an id, you will do:

```
var element = document.getElementById(popup_id_here);
```

Then. You can get the computed style of the element. Using this:

```
var style = getComputedStyle(element);
```

Now, you can check, if the display is flex:

```
if(style.display == "flex") ......
```

Apply the style to the body

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
```

Comment: This does not appear to be working, but I am fairly new to JS/JQ so I probably formatted it wrong. How does this look?
~~~
<script type="text/javascript">
 function body_no_scroll(){
  var element = document.getElementById(designpost-one);
  var style = getComputedStyle(element);
  if(style.display == "flex")
    
  var elements = document.getElementsByName("body");
  var bodyElement = elements[0];
  bodyElement.style.overflow = "hidden";
 }
</script>
~~~

Comment: function body_no_scroll() {
    var element = document.getElementById('id-of-popup');
    var style = getComputedStyle(element); 
    if (style.display == "flex") {
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    }
}